# Shorter way to write a python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

Is there a shorter way to write this in Python?
Here d is a python dictionary and a is a numpy array.

```
i = 0
for b in a:
    d[b] = a[:,i]
    i += 1
```

`

Answer (score 3):

A [dict comp](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
d = {b: a[:,i] for i,b in enumerate(a)}
```

`enumerate` gives you the index of each element in `a` which is equivalent to your `i` variable. The first variable in the dict comp is the key, the second is the value which is equivalent to `d[b] = a[:,i]`.

On a side note, if `b` happens to repeat then you will only get the last value for the repeated `b` as dicts cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `enumerate` iterator:

```
for i, b in enumerate(a):
    d[b] = a[:,i]
```

And since you're going into a dict, you can do this:

```
d.update((b, a[:,i]) for i, b in enumerate(a))
```